# Number of working days between today and working day till end of the year

Tags: sql

help please.

Trying to calculate the number of working days between today and the number of working says till end of the year in SQL.

I have started with the below.. The Date diff only does the number of days between today and end of the year.. but I need it for working days - i.e. where cal.Weekday = ' 'OR HOLIDAY.DateInfo>' '

```
CASe
  when  cal.Weekday = ' 'OR HOLIDAY.DateInfo>' ' then 0 else 1 end as workingdays,
  DateDiff("y",GETDATE(),DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YYYY,0,@StartDate)+1,0)) ) as enddateddd,
```

Comment: A working day is defined as Monday - Friday, excluding holidays?

Comment: Yes hence cal.Weekday = ' 'OR HOLIDAY.DateInfo>' ' carters for only working days and when I sum it, I get 249

Comment: You have a calendar and a (seperate) holiday table right?  Can we see those layouts, please?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you working days (M-F only), as for holdays I have no idea what your holidays are, so you'll need to add that part:

```
DECLARE @today AS DATE = GETDATE();
DECLARE @firstOfNextYear AS DATE = CAST('1/1/' + STR(1 + YEAR(GETDATE())) AS DATE);

WITH L0 AS (SELECT 1 AS C UNION ALL SELECT 1),       --      2
     L1 AS (SELECT L0.C FROM L0 CROSS JOIN L0 AS B), --      4
     L2 AS (SELECT L1.C FROM L1 CROSS JOIN L1 AS B), --     16
     L3 AS (SELECT L2.C FROM L2 CROSS JOIN L2 AS B), --    256
     L4 AS (SELECT L3.C FROM L3 CROSS JOIN L3 AS B), --  65536
      N AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY L4.C) AS n FROM L4),
      D AS (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n - 1, @today) AS d, n FROM N)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM D
WHERE d < @firstOfNextYear
  AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
```